# how to find the max value and the previous max value in array

Tags: arrays, angular, max

I have an array of objects. I want to find the max value and the one before that.

```
arr : [{key:1, value: 1},{key:2, value: 2}, {key:3, value: 3}, {key:4, value: 4}, {key:5, value: 5}]

    let largest = 0;
    greater = 0;
    val = [];
    this.arr.forEach(aa => {
      if (largest < Number(aa.value)) {
        largest = Number(aa.value);
        greater = aa.key;
      }
    });
  }
```

The value of greater is 5; I want to get the value 4 too and push both of them to val array.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve the same is by using the Array prototype function `sort()`.

What you need to do is sort in descending order and grab the first two elements.

[MDN link for sort() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Here's how I would write it.

```
let newArr = arr.sort(function(a, b){
                      return b.value-a.value;
                     });
```

Now you can grab the top two values in `newArr`.

Answer (score 0):

Separate values of the array. Get the maximum value using `Math.max`, then `filter` your array and get another one which does not contain the `max1` value from the first search and do the same on the filtered array.

```js
const arr = [
     { key: 1, value: 1 },
     { key: 2, value: 2 }, 
     { key: 3, value: 3 }, 
     { key: 4, value: 4 }, 
     { key: 5, value: 5 }
];

const valuesMax1 = arr.map(item => item.value);
const max1 = Math.max(...valuesMax1);

const valuesMax2 = valuesMax1.filter(item => item !== max1);
const max2 = Math.max(...valuesMax2);

console.log(max1);
console.log(max2);
```

Another simple way is to sort array and get first two items

```js
const arr = [
         { key: 1, value: 1 },
         { key: 2, value: 2 }, 
         { key: 3, value: 3 }, 
         { key: 4, value: 4 }, 
         { key: 5, value: 5 }
];

const sorted = arr.sort((f,s) => s.value - f.value);

console.log(sorted[0].value);
console.log(sorted[1].value);
```